# MSYS throws the following error (problem with autotools and mingGW)

Tags: mingw, autotools, mingw-w64, msys, autoreconf

mysys throws the following error when I compile my source.

```
cd ../common/pcre-8.33 && autoreconf
aclocal: macro `_LT_DECL_SED' required but not defined
aclocal: macro `_LT_FUNC_STRIPNAME_CNF' required but not defined
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
make: *** [../common/pcre_win64/.libs/libpcre.a] Error 1
```

Here is what I did to setup my environment, don't know what I am doing wrong here.

1) downloaded mingGW (setting 64 bit, pthread) from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download, and installed it

I added the bin folder to the path variable on windows

2) I downloaded the msys utility from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/msys-core/msys-1.0.11/MSYS-1.0.11.exe/download?use_mirror=excellmedia

I then edited the ftab file as follows
c:/my mingw directory  /mingw
c:/my java directory /java

Afterwards I did the following as mentioned by mysys wiki
c:/mingw /mingw
c:/java /java

Install MSYS DTK 1.0 in C:\msys\1.0.
Install MSYS Core 1.0.11. It is an archive. Untar it in C:\msys\1.0.
Set the environment variable HOME to C:\msys\1.0\home

Now to install autotools I downloaded the source from here
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/autoconf.htm

Then I navigated to the source directory, and run the following command as mentioned in wiki, which run fine

./configure --prefix=/mingw
make
make install

Can anyone guide me, so I know what I am doing wrong, the the correct procedure for working it up. Thanks

Comment: The error message suggests a mismatch between the Autotools installed on your machine and those with which the project you are trying to build was set up.  But that begs the question: why are you trying to rebuild the project's build system?  Although there are time when doing so is needed, running `autoreconf` is *not* a normal part of building a project that has an Autotools-based build system.

Comment: Before anything else, try this: unpack the project's tarball into a fresh directory.  In that directory, run the standard build sequence: `configure; make; make install`.  No `autoreconf` unless you're prepared to do some build-system hacking.

Comment: Also, doesn't msys use `pacman` for package management?  It's fairly likely that there's already a package available for PCRE.  You oughtn't need to build it manually from the source tarball.

Comment: Consider removing MSYS and DTK, then install MSYS2 as it has a proper command-line package manager `pacman`. If you insist on sticking with MSYS, consider using the [mingw-get](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get/) installer to install autoconf, automake, and libtool rather than the gnuwin32 versions (which are older). However, those versions may still be too old, so you may need to build new ones from source. MSYS2, however, makes it pretty effortless. If this `pacman` is anything like Arch Linux, the line `pacman -Syu autoconf automake libtool` will install them